# Recover a removed page in order to investigate a bug report?

Tags: support, moderation

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1100806 links to https://askubuntu.com/questions/244043/bash-and-getcwd-fails-in-a-nest-directory-with-a-dash-in-the-command-line#comment303051_244043 which however comes up as "Removed for reasons of moderation".

Is there any way to recover at least the gist of this page so that the bug report can be investigated?

Comment: There is an undelete option for people at a certain rep.

Comment: Or you could ask a 10Ker nicely for a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks.  But how?  Just spam the ones who have high rep and have avatars I like?  I was hoping to reach some sort of moderator / official representative by posting here.

Comment: Just ask someone in Ubuntu Chat room with an @ get their attention.

Comment: It is worth noting that the link you provide is a direct link to Rinzwind's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question was closed and deleted as it was a bug report, I think it's alright to share what it was. I have saved that page as a PDF and uploaded to my Google Drive: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3BkhpnXbs3RVXJ0dVFaXzJkUmc/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: Thanks!  At least it allows me to identify @Hooked as the submitter (-:

Comment: @tripleee also take note of Rinzwind's comment.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the deleted question that isn't in the bug report.

Comment: Rinzwind'd confirmation comment is informative. Looks like the bug shows up only at some minimum level of nesting.